# Prevent duplicates in column with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, duplicates, timestamp

My column A contains a lot of unique timestamps.
Example:

> 22/08/2022 15:34:21

I want prevent users from copy pasting the values in column A, as I need to make sure values in column A remain unique.

This already means that this cannot be done with data validation, because data validation will not prevent the data being entered if they use copy/paste.

I tried with this script:

```
function PreventTimeStampDuplicate(e) {

  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const columnToCheck = 1; // Change this to the appropriate column number (1 for column A, 2 for B, etc.)

  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.getColumn() == columnToCheck && e.value !== null) {
    const values = sh.getRange(2, columnToCheck, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat();
    const uniqueValues = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (uniqueValues[values[i]]) {
        e.range.clearContent();
        showDialog("Duplicate Timestamp", "You have copied a timestamp. Timestamp copy automatically deleted in order to avoid show ID collision.");
        break; // Exit the loop early since we found a duplicate
      } else {
        uniqueValues[values[i]] = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

function showDialog(title, message) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(title, message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

Unfortunately, this right now deletes any input (but it shows the msg box).

It has to be mentioned that new data can be entered everywhere and not just the last row, by users, or by other scripts that I have running in the background.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I realized that the problem laid with the format of the timestamp.

Original timestamps were logged like this:

> 2022-10-11T10:41:14.363Z

While copied timestamps were logged like this:

> Tue, Oct 11, 2022, 10:41:14 AM GMT+2

I guess this is unexplicably stupid, because it means that when you copy-paste the timestamp to another cell, you automatically lose the info on the 1/1000 secs.

So, I had to adjust the format of the data that my copy is compared to. Here's my solution:

```
function PreventTimeStampDuplicate(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Check if the edited cell is in Column A and not empty
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1 && e.value !== "") {
    var newValue = formatDate(e.range.getValue());

    Logger.log(newValue);

    var columnData = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
    var isDuplicate = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < columnData.length; i++) {
      if (i != e.range.getRow() - 1) {
        var formattedValue = formatDate(columnData[i][0]);
        if (formattedValue === newValue) {
          isDuplicate = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    // Log the entire column data
    Logger.log("Column Data: " + JSON.stringify(columnData));

    if (isDuplicate) {
      // Log that it's a duplicate
      Logger.log("Is Duplicate: Yes");

      // Delete the newly added value
      e.range.setValue("");

      // Show a message box
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Duplicate Timestamp deleted");
    } else {
      // Log that it's not a duplicate
      Logger.log("Is Duplicate: No");
    }
  }
}

// Function to format the date to the desired format for the script
function formatDate(date) {
  var options = {
    weekday: "short",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
    timeZoneName: "short",
  };
  return date.toLocaleString("en-US", options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep column one unique

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value != null) {
    e.source.toast("Gate");
    const vs = [...new Set(sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().filter(e => e > 0))].sort((a,b) => a - b).map(e => [e]);//numerical sort
    //const vs = [...new Set(sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().filter(e => e > 0))].sort().map(e => [e]);//alpha betical sort take your pick
    sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).clearContent();
    sh.getRange(2, 1, vs.length).setValues(vs);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, copy-pasting a timestamp into another cell of column A is still possible (value is not being cleared).
No need to sort the values (it's actually important that the order stays untouched).
What your script does right now: If value is unique: Shows "Gate" and sorts all values.
if value is not unique: Shows "Entry" and does nothing else.